# how can I quickly check to see if a wmic product exists using batch?

Tags: batch-file, product, uninstallation, wmic, querying

I am trying to uninstall software using:

```
wmic product where name="XXXXXXX" call uninstall
```

how can I quickly check to see if a wmic product exists with a batch file without querying all products, which can take some time for the batch to execute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`reg query` is arguably the fastest method, but not as reliable, theoretically.

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData /f "Exact Product Name" /s /d /e|find "DisplayName">nul
if errorlevel 1 reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData /f "Exact Product Name" /s /d /e|find "DisplayName">nul
if errorlevel 1 echo "Exact Product Name" NOT FOUND IN REGISTRY
```

To find all exact product names containing `Microsoft`:

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData /s /v "DisplayName" | find "Microsoft"
```

Comment: where do I find the "exact" name and the "display" name?

Comment: it is also showing an error of 0 even though I uninstalled it and I run the code again.

Comment: hmm... it could be because you are using linux and I'm using windows? I'm not too sure. I changed your "if errorlevel 1" to "if %errorlevel% equ 1" and it seems to work. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok. Now I'm checking to see if 64bit applications are installed. I can't use the wmic to find the exact name. The Control Panel uninstaller name doesn't work. Do you know how I can find the correct name?

Comment: 1. delete `/e` 2. leave `DisplayName` unchanged: `reg query ....... /s /v "DisplayName" | find "Microsoft"` Basically it lists values of all records named DisplayName, then filters the list by the word Microsoft.

Comment: That would better be a new question I think as those aren't `wmic products`, are they?